# How to use getReserves() in a forEach loop?

Tags: web3js, truffle, javascript, uniswap

How can I use getReserves inside a `forEach` loop to call the reserves relative to each array object (the array objects are token addresses)? Details below:

I have an array of addresses being monitored inside a forEach loop like so:

```
const arbFor = process.env.ARB_FOR 
const arbAgainst = ["address1","address2","address3"]
let i = 0;

arbAgainst.forEach(()=>{

  const main = async () => {
    const { token0Contract, token1Contract, token0, token1 } = await getTokenAndContract(arbFor, arbAgainst[i])
    var uPair = await getPairContract(uFactory, token0.address, token1.address)
    uniPair = Object.freeze(uPair);
    var sPair = await getPairContract(sFactory, token0.address, token1.address)
    sushiPair = Object.freeze(sPair);
    
    // Do some stuff

  // Other async functions

  const determineProfitability = async (_routerPath, _token0Contract, _token0, _token1,  exchange, token0, token1) => {
    console.log(`Determining Profitability...\n`)

    let reserves, exchangeToBuy, exchangeToSell

    if (_routerPath[0]._address == uRouter._address) {
        reserves = await getReserves(sushiPair)
        exchangeToBuy = 'Uniswap'
        exchangeToSell = 'Sushiswap'
    } else {
        reserves = await getReserves(uniPair)
        exchangeToBuy = 'Sushiswap'
        exchangeToSell = 'Uniswap'
    }

    console.log(`Reserves on ${_routerPath[1]._address}\n`)
    console.log(`Token 1: ${web3.utils.fromWei(reserves[0].toString(), 'ether')}`)
    console.log(`Token 0: ${web3.utils.fromWei(reserves[1].toString(), 'ether')}\n`)
}
```

As you can see, I've been attempting to use `Object.freeze` to work with a specific object for that iteration of the `forEach` loop.  However, when I run this, it seems to only freeze one time and attempt to iterate over that same object each time.  So clearly it doesn't freeze anew for each array object.

However, if I simply use `uPair` and `sPair` inside `getReserves()` I get the following error stack:

```
  const reserves = await _pairContract.methods.getReserves().call()
                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'methods')
    at getReserves (/Users/Me/trading_bot_V2/helpers/helpers.js:54:42)
    at calculatePrice (/Users/Me/trading_bot_V2/helpers/helpers.js:59:40)
    at checkPrice (/Users/Me/trading_bot_V2/bot.js:105:34)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Subscription.callback (/Users/Me/trading_bot_V2/bot.js:40:45)
```

Any thoughts?

**Update - I removed `var` from in front of `uPair` and `sPair`.  Now they're behaving exactly like `uniPair` and `sushiPair` did.  Which is to say they're only looping through a single `reserves` router path.  And I think it's also worth noting that path doesn't change ever regardless of which swap I identify first (say USDT/WETH or DAI/WETH)

Edit - I realized it may be beneficial to see the `getReserves()` function, as it is used differently in this case.  Here are the relevant functions:

```
async function getPairAddress(_V2Factory, _token0, _token1) {
    const pairAddress = await _V2Factory.methods.getPair(_token0, _token1).call()
    return pairAddress
}

async function getPairContract(_V2Factory, _token0, _token1) {
    const pairAddress = await getPairAddress(_V2Factory, _token0, _token1)
    const pairContract = new web3.eth.Contract(IUniswapV2Pair.abi, pairAddress)
    return pairContract
}

async function getReserves(_pairContract) {
    const reserves = await _pairContract.methods.getReserves().call()
    return [reserves.reserve0, reserves.reserve1]
```

***Update 2: I've JUST noticed that when I call `` console.log(`Reserves on ${_routerPath[1]._address}\n`) `` it's actually printing the router address for sushiswap or uniswap rather than pulling reserves.  Might have something to do with it.  Still open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here ended up being that `uPair` (which I didn't tell you because I didn't know it was important here) is a global variable with no initial definition. It was defined in `main()` and I never actually called it in to `checkPrice`

Answer (score 0):

I would have an array with the addresses of all pairs and would do something like this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < allPairs.length; i++){
  const pair = new ethers.Contract(allPairs[i], UniswapV2Pair.abi, provider)
const reserves = await pair.getReserves()

pairWithReserves.push({pair: allPair[i], reserve0: reserves.token0, reserve1: reserves.token1})
```

This would be enough. It's just a glimpse on how you can solve this easily.

BROTIP: If it's for arbitrage, you should be looking for `kLast()` insteed of `getReserves()`

Comment: Thanks so much!  What's the benefit of ```kLast()``` over ```getReserves()```?

Comment: Also, any chance you could put this example in Web3js terms?  I don't use ethers haha

Comment: kLast returns the quociente of getReserves.

Comment: I dont work with web3.js for years but the approach is Just create istance for the pair contract and call the function.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!  After a lot of trial and error, I realized I was asking the wrong question.  But this should definitely help others!   You should link your Medium article about ```kLast()``` here too